# Sql script display leading 0 in excel output file

Tags: excel, shell, sql-scripts

I have sql script "example.sql": `SPOOL &1 Select '<.TR>'||'<.TD align="left">'||column_name||'<./TD>'||'<.TR>' from table1; spool off..`which dumps it contents to cshell script "getdata.csh" this is how i get data from sql script to csh script `sqlplus $ORA_UID/$ORA_PSWD @${SQL}example.sql ${DATA}${ext}` once i extract data from it i create a excel file by combining 3 files  header. html `<html>
<.head>
<.title)
Title
<./title>
<./head>
<.body>
<.table >
<.tr>
<.th>Column Name<./th>
<.tr>`ext file that has query results and trailer.html `<./tr>
<./table>
<./body>
<./html>` and i save this file as .xls and send it through email as attachment.. Now my problem is Column_name has data that starts with 0 but when i open excel file leading 0 are gone but i wanna keep that 0.. so what can i add to make sure that email attached excel file will have leading 0 when that is opened on the other side.. plz any help would be good

Comment: you need to be much more specific (query, how you're running it, RDBMS type, etc...)

Comment: is there any other way to do this.. none of these answers will work for me

Comment: I have sql script which dumps its output to cshell script which generates excel file and sends email.. getting data from oracle.. sql script looks like this: SPOOL &1 Select '<.TR>'||'<.TD align="left">'||column_name||'<./TD>'||'<.TR>' from table1; spool off.. i need a way to make sure leading 0 in some of the data get shown when dumped to the excel file

Comment: Per Mat's original comment, please edit your original posting and insert (and correctly format) the code you included above. Also, you might want to tell us how the results from SQL is being read into Excel. From a tab-delimited file named with extension .xls, OR via Excel VB, OR ??? There are too many things that might be affecting this.

Answer (score 0):

Using oracle:

Say your attribute is called 'number'

```
select '0' || to_char(number) as number
from table mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the excel object model, or a macro to go into the excel file grab the column and change the formatting.

In your case:

```
Range("A1").Numberformat = "@"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're generating the excel file on the fly, you could prepend those numbers with an apostrophe, ie   '

This causes Excel to treat the number like a string. The only downside is it might cause some side effects if the sheet has any equations that use those numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I have dealt with this issue in the past, and the problem is strictly a "feature" of Excel formatting. Unfortunately, I don't have the resources to completely test an answer, but here are two things you can try.

1. Add a step inside your cshell script to surround your $1 value with ="",

awk '{$1= "="" $1 """; print $0}' inFile > outFile

The downside is that you're now telling Excel to treat these values as strings. If you're doing any fancy calculations on these values you may have different problems.

2. #2 (why does SO formatting always renumber numbered blocks as 1 !;-!) . As this is really an Excel formatting problem AND in my recollection, you can't retrieve the leading zero once the file has been opened and processed, I seem to remember I had a trick of pre-formatting a black worksheet, saving it as a template, and then loading the file into the template. I recall that was tricky too, so don't expect it to work. You might have to consult Excel users on the best tactics if #1 above doesn't work.

You might also want to tell people what version of Excel you are using, if you go to them for help.

IHTH